# Close an MS Access laccdb file that was opened with an append query

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am running an append query from VBA in an access front end file. the query runs on a table that is in another database that is not connected to the front end. (it is an archive of data from the connected back end) here is the query:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO " & tblNames(i) & " IN '" & archiveFile & "' " & _
                "SELECT " & tblNames(i) & ".* " & _
                "FROM " & tblNames(i) & ""
```

I am using an array to cycle through each table that I want to archive. and the 'archiveFile' variable is passed in as a parameter depending on which accdb file I need to send the data to.

My problem is this: the sql statement works but when it is done the archive file remains locked. In other words, an laccdb is opened for the archive file that I append to, and it will remain open until I shut down the front end (the file that I ran the vba from)

my question; Is there a way to close that connection made by the "DoCmd.RunSQL" there is nothing that I opened that I have access to to close, that I can tell. yet something is being created and left hanging... thanks in advance. I'll be happy to clarify or share more of my code if needed. (if there is a better way of doing this, I am all ears)

Update:

I tried running the query from the gui instead of from the VBA code and I got the same results. The laccdb file was created and could not be removed unless I closed the front end from which the query was run. I am hoping there is a way to call up open connections and then close them.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. No need to worry about that.

Comment: I agree that it is normal for the lock file to show up when a query is running on data in a database file. However the issue was that the lock file would not go away. This behavior is not desirable or correct, although I would have to agree is common if not normal when working with Access. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing around with the data connection, not only with the archive file (which is not linked to the front end) but also with the back end which is linked. I found this article [performanceldblocking](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performanceldblocking.htm) about improving performance by maintaining a permanent link with the back end file. After I did that, somehow, although it seems somewhat unrelated to me, the archive lock file doesn't stick. it blinks in an out as the various queries run and when they are finished archiving data, the lock file is gone and no longer causes issues.

again, I am not sure exactly why but setting up a persistent connection to the back end seems to have solved the issue so that the archive file is not confused about my front end still being connected to it.